# Packaging a Python script that can be run on a computer that doesn't have Python installed?

Tags: python, ipython

I have a Python script (that manipulates files on a shared drive). I would like to turn that script into a file (maybe .exe?) that perhaps can be double-clicked and run on a machine that doesn't have Python installed. Is that possible/easy to do?

Comment: Take a look at PyInstaller, py2exe, cx_freeze (in that order, according to my experiences)

Answer (score 1):

You can try `py2exe`.

Tutorials can be found at http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial

Answer (score 1):

I use and recommend pyinstaller. If you need only **one executable file**, you need to install pyinstaller and call executable passing these arguments:

```
pyinstaller.exe your_script.py --onefile --windowed
```

This options can be used when you generate the executable file: https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/usage.html#options

To install: http://www.pyinstaller.org/

Documentation: https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/